# Globally initialized variable changes to 'nil' in Swift UIView XIB?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

I have globally initialised variable inside a `UIView` class.

The variable is `statusLabel` as string. I have assigned a value for `statusLabel` in Pickerview `didSelectRow` delegate method.
There i'm getting the value for string. However When the delegate finishes the value of string changes to `nil`

It's all same for all other Globally initialised variable.
What Could be the reason?

Thanks in Advance

```
class CustomPickerMenu: UIView,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate
{
    var statusLabel = String()

    var pickerArray = [String]()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        pickerArray = ["None","Connections","All"]
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
         print("Awake with coder")

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if(row == 0)
        {
            statusLabel = pickerArray[row]
        }
        if(row == 1)
        {
            statusLabel = pickerArray[row]
        }
        if(row == 2)
        {
            statusLabel = pickerArray[row]
        }
      print("statusLabel : " + statusLabel)
    }

    @IBAction func saveStatus(_ sender: Any)
    {   
        delegate?.statusChange(controller: self, text:statusLabel)
        self.delegate?.showNavigationController(controller: self)

        print("statusLabel : " + statusLabel)
    }
```

here is the output for statusLabel during didselectrow delegate(1st three outputs) and save status(last output)
[image]

Comment: Put actual code in question in place of images

Comment: 1. As @Rajat mentioned in above comment, add code not images. 2. Add the code where you actually try to access the variable and find it to be null.

Comment: Here is the full code

Comment: what type does `pickerArray` have?

Comment: I have edited your question to only keep the relevant code. In future, please don not add 'full' code in the question when not required. Try to make it easier for people understand your question.

Comment: @lukya Hey buddy, Thanks

Comment: @marosoaie pickerArray is an array of strings

Comment: What do you mean by _the value of string changes to 'nil'_ ? Its not an optional variable so it cannot be nil. Are you getting an error or a crash?

Comment: @lukya the app crashes at the end of the delegate where it call "statusLabel". I put a break in the picker Delegate function and saveStatus delegate. when the picker function breaks, statuslable gets a string value. But when the second break calls, the statusLabel changes to nil, the app crashes showing nil in the variable

Comment: `statusLabel` cannot be nil. It's not an optional value (String)

Comment: I have declared the variable as global right?? then why the value changes after the picker function finishes

Comment: It looks like you're force unwrapping `delegate` in save status. Can you try relacing ! with ? and see what happens?

Comment: Your 'saveStatus method starts with `self.delegate!.showNavigationController(controller: self)`. Are you sure the app does not crash trying to unwrap the `self.delegate` object?

Comment: @lukya It didn't crash. The value of status label changed to nil...

Comment: @marosoaie the same... no difference... still the value of string is nil

Comment: print stasutLabel `print("statusLabel : " + statusLabel)
` value at the end of `picker: didSelectRow:` and beginning of `saveStatus`

Comment: I did, still displaying every string during "didselectrow" delegate, but no value in "saveStatus".

Comment: Can you just update the question with 'print' statements and the console log (from the added print statements).

Comment: @lukya edited the query with the output

Comment: 1. Move the `statusChange:` delegate method above `showNavigationController ` method as chances are the show method is removing the view controller, (there by loosing reference to statusLabel) before passing statusLabel delegate's `statusChange:` method. 2. What actions do you perform in statusChange:?

Comment: 1. I changed it earlier... moved statusChange above showNavigationController a while before, forgotted to update the code... still  no value to statusLabel :-(  2. I need the string value in the previous controller. I'm just assigning it to a label text.

Comment: @lukya Thanks for the help... got the solution

Comment: @marosoaie Thanks for the help buddy

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, more than that it was a mistake. the class the I used "CustomPickerMenu" got called more than one time. During init(frame) and init(decoder). Thats the reason the value of string initially assigns during 1st call and changes to nil during 2nd call.

I initially connected the delegates to xib through the storyboard, Then I called the xib class from one view controller, which will eventually be calling the xib init(frame). I wrote the code to load the xib in it's init(frame). Since I already connected the xib with the storyboard, xib will also call it init(coder) method.

so what I did was, removed the delegates from storyboard and called "self.pickerView.delegate" and "self.pickerView.dataSource" in its init(frame), eventually the init(coder) method stop calling.

Now, the value of string is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Do these checks and see if your code follows the same.
`delegate` is a weak variable.

- As delegate is an optional, make sure you do not force unwrap it. Use `?` instead of `!`.
- Make sure the Protocol is being implemented by the class that this delegate points to.
- Make sure that `delegate` variable is assigned with `self` in the implemented class.

A sample playground demo would be.

```
class CustomPickerMenu
{
    var statusLabel = String()

    var pickerArray = [String]()
    weak var delegate:Sample?

    func call() {
        pickerArray = ["One", "Two"]
        print(pickerArray)
    }
    func pick()
    {
        statusLabel = pickerArray[0]
        print(statusLabel)
    }

    @IBAction func saveStatus(_ sender: Any)
    {
        print(statusLabel)
        self.delegate?.doSomething(data: statusLabel)
        print(statusLabel)
    }
}

class Apply: Sample {

    func test() {
        let picker = CustomPickerMenu()
        picker.call()
        picker.pick()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.saveStatus(self)
    }
    func doSomething(data: String) {
        print(data)
    }
}

let apply = Apply()
apply.test()
```

Comment: You don't have to. This is just a sample. As this is an `IBAction` , if you had connected this with your button from the Storyboard/XIB, the button instance would be passed to it.